# python copy all files larger than x then rename all new files

Tags: python, python-3.5

I need a script to copy all files larger than 5mb from a given folder to a new folder that the script needs to create on desktop. Then it needs to rename all files in increasing order also changing extension. 
For example files: slides.ppt, math.doc, essay.docx
to:lec1.doc, lec2.doc, lec3.doc

I got this script to work and it lists all files larger than 5mb:

```
import os

# The directory that we are interested in
myPath = "C:\asd"

# The min size of the file in Bytes
mySize = '5000000'

# All the file paths will be stored in this list
filesList= []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
    for name in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(path, name))

for i in filesList:
    # Getting the size in a variable
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(str(i))

    # Print the files that meet the condition
    if int(fileSize) >= int(mySize):
        print("The File: " + str(i) + " is: " + str(fileSize) + " Bytes")
```

Now this prints out the list and the list is correct but how can I go from here?
I looked into os and glob but I'm having a hard time figuering this out.

Thank you guys for helping out.

Dany

Comment: start with a simple example, outside of your script. e.g. try `glob.glob('/path/to/files/*.doc')` and see what you get. search for rename in the python docs, there are at least two ways to do that (os and pathlib both offer a rename function).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) package. It handles high level file operations

```
import shutil
#do something
shutil.move(source,destination)
```

where source and destination might be files or folders.
Just set destination to the final name of the file, instead of copying and then renaming.

Comment: as I commented @Luca I got it working with shutil and have everything in new directory but now I cant get the os.rename to work.. posted the error and code above

Comment: problem was that I used only filename in os.rename but I needed to include full path. Problem resolved! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename` method from `os`

```
import os
os.rename(src, dst)
```

where the `src` is the original file or directory name and `dst` is the new name.

Comment: ok I got my script working it copies all my files to the new directory    'destPath = "C:/Users/dquerzola/Desktop/scuola"' but now from here I can't do the rename

Comment: 'n=1
filenames = os.listdir(destPath)

for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, 'lezione'+str(n)+'.docx')'

Comment: Exception "unhandled FileNotFoundError"
[WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato: 'reg32.dll' -> 'lezione1.docx'
File: C:\Users\dquerzola\Desktop\doc\pyth\scripts\list.py, Line: 33        in english that's: Impossible finding the specified file